# Почему иногда закрывается "модальное" окно при клике в нем?

Tags: html, css, modal

```js
$('.buy-keys').on('mouseenter',function(event) {
  if ( document.body.clientWidth > 790 ){
    $('.buy-keys-modal').show();
    opacity('on');
  }
}).on('mouseleave',(function(event) {
  if ( document.body.clientWidth > 790 ){
    $('.buy-keys-modal').hide();
    opacity('off')
  }
}));
```

```css
.buy-keys-modal{
  display: none;
   z-index: 99;
   position: absolute;
   width: 410px;
   height: 195px;
   background: #171717;
   cursor: default;
   
}
```

При наведении на .buy-keys открывается .buy-keys-modal и там есть кнопки, но если кликать внутри модалки, то иногда(редко) оно просто закрывается

```html
<div class="nav-item buy-keys">
                <div>BUY KEYS</div>
                <div class="buy-keys-modal">
                  <h4>Quick buy keys</h4>
                  <div class="keys-stacks">
                    <div class="keys-stack keys-1" data-value="1">1</div>
                    <div class="keys-stack keys-5" data-value="4">4</div>
                    <div class="keys-stack keys-10" data-value="10">10</div>
                    <div class="keys-stack keys-25" data-value="20">20</div>
                    <div class="keys-stack keys-50" data-value="50">50</div>
                    <div class="keys-stack keys-100" data-value="100">100</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="total-keys-value">Total: <strong>0$</strong></div>
                  <div class="confirm-keys">
                    <div class="confirm-button" id="confirm-keys" disabled>CONFIRM YOUR PURCHASE</div>
                    <div class="user-keys-value"><input max="500" maxlength="4" type="text" name="keyscount"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="stripe"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Закрываете как, с помощью JS?. Так или иначе делайте закрытие только по клику конкретного элемента: кнопка, область. И убедитесь, что `z-index` настроен верно.

Comment: вот так `$('.buy-keys').on('mouseenter',function(event) {
  if ( document.body.clientWidth > 790 ){
    $('.buy-keys-modal').show();
    opacity('on');
  }
}).on('mouseleave',(function(event) {
  if ( document.body.clientWidth > 790 ){
    $('.buy-keys-modal').hide();
    opacity('off')
  }
}));`